# How can i enable multi selection on TAdvStringGrid?

Tags: tms

How i can enable multi line selection on TadvStringGrid (tms) without the use of ctrl key? I've check on the pdf manual but there is only the advice of use ctrl for enable this option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get my work done, just need to read carefully the manual and think about it.
I need to keep a list with previous selected cell and after set grid.MouseActions.DisjunctRowSelect and set the selection with the grid function myGrid.SelectRows(myRow,1).